# Contractible manifold that is not uniformly contractible?

Tags: geometry, differential-topology

I'm looking for an example of a contractible Riemannian manifold which is not uniformly contractible.

**Definition:** Let $ X $ be a metric space. We say $ X $ is uniformly contractible, if for all $r>0$ we have a $R>r$ such that
every $r$-ball $ B_r(x) $ around any point $ x \in X $ is contractible inside the
bigger ball $ B_R(x) \supset B_r(x) $.

In general I'm quite unclear about the notion of uniform contractibility. Is there any references which I can look at?

Comment: You misstated the definition of uniform contractibility. Which books on coarse geometry and geometric group theory did you check?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you please tell me what the correct definition is? Also right now I'm looking at John Roe's "Lectures on coarse geometry". He says "X is uniformly contractible if, for every $R>0$ there is $S>0$ such that, for every $x \in X$, the inclusion $B(x;R) \to B(x; S)$ is nullhomotopic".

Comment: That's the right definition. Now compare to what you wrote. It is all about the right order of quantifiers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a sequence of round 2-spheres $S(x_i, i)$ of the radius $i$. Now, remove from each sphere an open  spherical cap with the perimeter of the unit length. The result is a contractible surface $S_i$ with boundary $C_i$ with the path metric induced from the sphere. But the contractivity function diverges to infinity as $i\to \infty$ because you need the entire surface to contract the circle $C_i$ to a point. Next, you want to connect the surfaces $S_i$ to form a contractible space. The simplest thing to do is just to wedge them at one point and take a path-metric. That's your example. With a bit more thought, you can modify this example to get a contractible Riemannian surface which is not uniformly contractible. You drill countably many holes in the plane so that each hole has unit circumference. Attach $S_i$ along the boundary of each hole. Lastly, smooth out the metric along each $C_i$.

Comment: perfect, thanks.